# RHSA installation in RH7

Tags: array

this is a question similar to the mine I asked you yesterday (how to iterate installation in a row).
I need a script that starting from an RHSA list as argument, separated by " " spaces, it performs this command in one row **but** with commas instead of space. For example, the argument of the script is the list

```
FIRST_RHSA SECOND_RHSA THIRD_RHSA
```

and the script has to run as

```
yum -y -v update --advisory=FIRST_RHSA,SECOND_RHSA,THIRD_RHSA
```

I tried using array with character substitutions but it doesn't run correctly.
Do you have an idea please?

thanks

Comment: If all else fails, `$(echo 'string with spaces' | /bin/tr ' ' ',')` is the string with spaces replaced by commas.

Answer (score 0):

```
varbl="FIRST_RHSA SECOND_RHSA THIRD_RHSA"

yum -y -v update --advisory="${varbl// /,}"
```

You could use bash parameter substitution